# Arbitrary stream name

Tags: c++, stream

My question is very simple, yet I can't seem to find a proper solution. In order to create or open a stream in c++ you use the following syntax :

```
ifstream input_data("data.txt")
```

I want the thing inside the brackets to be a variable chosen by the user.(I basically want the user to chose the name of the text file in which his data will be stored in or loaded from)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Placement of punctuation matters in C++.  And an interesting article about that: http://www.flounder.com/bricks.htm

Comment: It was a typing mistake. My question still stands, but thanks for pointing that out I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: You will need to prompt the user, getting the user's choice into a variable.  You can then use that in the stream constructor.  You have a number of choices for prompting the user, but the best choice depends on your environment (OS, etc).

Comment: string awe = "asd.txt";
 ifstream input_data;
 input_data.open(awe);

This compiles, however it doesn't create a text file. (Or worst case scenario it does but I can't find it.)

Comment: @Bloodcount: That's a good start; definitely on the right track.  Put that in your question (use the edit link under the question).  Then, you may find that you need to say `open(awe.c_str())`, depending on how new your library is.

Comment: WAIT I figured it out. The way which JimP said works. My problem was that I was trying to do things with a ifstream variable which can be done only with an ofstream variable. The mistake is mine.

Comment: @Bloodcount: Since you have the answer you want. Do you mind posting the answer to your question below.

Comment: @Loki Astari I added the answer to the first post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Moved from question:

In this case, input_data is a constructor which takes a string, so you just need to put there a
string. A good way of solving it is the following:

```
string a;              // declare the string
cin >> a;              // let the user input the name
a = a + ".txt";        // add the extension
ifstream input_data(a);// run the constructor with the string as an argument.
```

Note: In C++03 you need to convert the string into a C-String. It was not until C++11 that fstream took a string as input to the constructor.

```
ifstream input_data(a.c_str()); // Required for C++03
```